# Do screen recording software make the game laggy?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, performance, screen-recorder, obs-studio

Let's take an example of Counter Strike 1.6 game (**offline**, with bots). And an i7 system with 16GB RAM and 940MX graphics.

As you know, it is very old game so this graphic card is more than okay for this game.

I didn't observe any lag/performance issue in the game, but I'm thinking a ***logic*** that can make the game *non-smooth* (non smooth just like we play a modern graphics rich game on very low FPS like 30 FPS with poor graphics card). I'm just curious.

And let's take example of **OBS studio** for recording with 30-40 FPS. So I feel, this software will take screenshots 30 to 40 times per second to for full time till you want to record a game. So I feel this will make the game non-smooth or causing lags, because it will interrupt the game 30 to 40 times each second, so game performance should be little low quality.

Is this ***logic*** correct? Do recording software behave like this?

Comment: Can there be a performance impact of recording gameplay of Counter Strike, it absolutely is possible, but that is entirely dependent on hardware.  OBS Studio creates a video file that is 30FPS it does not create 30 screenshots per second.  Likewise, if you are worried about performance, have you tested it?  If you don't notice any performance impact of recording a file, then there is no performance impact, this is confirmed by comparing the performance benchmarks before (without recording gameplay) and after (recording gameplay).

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I kind of didn't notice it. When I recorded my game on 30FPS, the video isn't very smooth as  compared to original gameplay. Game was much better and smooth. So I'm thinking to increase OBS FPS to 60 FPS, hence I asked this question so I'll know better if it would impact the game smoothness.

Comment: If you record 60 GPS gameplay as a video that is only 30 FPS then I would expect the output video to be choppy.  The only way to know the impact is to run benchmarks.

Comment: @Ramhound you mean run benchmarks with 60FPS recording, right? And any starting idea how to do that? I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Play the game and run the benchmarking capabilities of Counter Strike (if it exists), if it does not exist (notate the FPS).  Once you have a baseline run the same test while you record the gameplay with OBS Studio, note the FPS, and compare the two results.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically yes.

If your game is running as fast as the computer can run it, then some time slices must be given up to the recorder. It may be intercepting the images after they left the CPU, somewhere along the DirectX or OpenGL path, but even to do this it's stealing slices from the GPU.
Once it's done that it needs to compress the video & save to HD/SSD. This again has impact, however slight, on the operation of the rest of the system.

In practise you may never notice, if the machine is not already running at capacity.